# Best way of retrieving a collection of SPSite in code

Tags: spquery, spsite

I have a page where the user will be entering a data in a textbox, and click submit, and it brings all site collections that url contains this data in textbox, I am currenlty doing a Linq query to bring all sites from the current web app where the url contains this textbox value, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, and I am not sure if this way deals well with all SPSite disposale, I don't know if I should dispose of these objects or not. Any help?

Comment: Can you share the code you have?

Comment: It's something like List<SPSite> sites = (from s in webapp.Sites where s.Url.Contains(txtsite.Text) select s).ToList<SPSite>();

Comment: each time the user searches it will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to dispose the SPSite objects and write an extension method for that since it is in LINQ. However, you can also achieve your result using `foreach` loops instead of LINQ.

See this for more information on using LINQ and SharePoint objects which need to be disposed like `SPSite` and `SPWeb`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657095/using-linq-with-sharepoint-and-disposing-of-objects
http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/05/linq-for-spwebcollection-revisited-assafeenumerable/

Comment: Is there a way to call this list of sites using REST or REST would not do it?

Comment: Thanks nadeem, but why he mentioned that this won't compile? : var webs = from w in site.AllWebs
            orderby w.Title
            select w.Title;

Comment: I don't think it is possible with REST. In SP 2013 there is end point for Site collections and Webs but not for web applications. See this http://www.tikalk.com/net/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-%E2%80%93-search-service

Comment: The answer is there the type of 'w' is not defined.